# Mongo DB Connection Delay

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using mongodb with spring. When creating a `MongoClient` from uri, creating connection to a mongo db cluster (**MongoDB Atlas**) takes around 5 seconds. Once connection is established the queries do not take much time. It does service discovery to find the primary and secondary replica sets which would take some time but is 5 second duration a normal behavior ? I need to deploy services on Cloud Run and hence need fast startup time.

Java Version - 11
Spring Version - 2.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: What kind of Cluster are you using? And what kind of answer do you expect?
Yes, it's normal, for M0 when you are sitting in India, and your cluster is in US/EU (London)

Comment: Thanks. Currently using M0 cluster located in EU. I tried to deploy the service on EU cloud run and the connection time got reduced to 1.5 seconds